# Azure data explorer ingestionbatching policy is not working as expected

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I tried to ingest the records to the target table from the source table with the update policy and ingestion batching policy.
Data records count in the target table keep on increasing in seconds even when the ingestion batching policy has been updated to one hour.

```
> .alter tables TestTable policy ingestionbatching
> @'{"MaximumBatchingTimeSpan":"01:00:00", "MaximumNumberOfItems": 100,
> "MaximumRawDataSizeMB": 500}'
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/batchingpolicy#sealing-a-batch) is quite clear about it:

> The following list shows the **basic** batching policy triggers to seal a
> batch. **A batch is sealed and ingested when the first condition is met**:
>
> - `Size`: Batch size limit reached or exceeded
> - `Count`: Batch file number limit reached
> - `Time`: Batching time has expired

In addition:

> The following list shows conditions to seal batches related to single
> blob ingestion. A batch is sealed and ingested when the conditions are
> met:
>
> `SingleBlob_FlushImmediately`: Ingest a single blob because
> 'FlushImmediately' was set
> `SingleBlob_IngestIfNotExists`: Ingest a
> single blob because 'IngestIfNotExists' was set
> `SingleBlob_IngestByTag`: Ingest a single blob because 'ingest-by' was set
> `SingleBlob_SizeUnknown`: Ingest a single blob because blob size is
> unknown

Comment: no even the size and count  has not yet reached the limit. data count was increasing even by 2 but still data gets ingested to target table.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Were you able to find the relevant setup?